# jQuery dynamically added class does not fire

Tags: jquery-ui

```
<a href="#" class='gbutton yen_form' rel="overlay-box1">Next</a>

$('yen_form').click(function(){
  //some validations done here
  $(this).addClass('overlay');
});

$('overlay').click(function(){
  //overlay appears
})
```

First function fires correctly but the second 'overlay' class function does not fired at all.
If I added overlay to the anchor it works properly. why???

Can any one solve this or I am doing anything wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Use the live method
$(".overlay").live("click", function() {
});

NB After adding the class to the anchor, live event will fire immediately.
Can't you just show the overlay rather than adding a class?
Use the code below

```
$('.yen_form').click(function(){
  //some validations done here
  $(this).addClass('overlay');
});

$('.overlay').live("click", function(){
  //overlay appears
});
```